# Numerate duplicate of every value

Tags: postgresql

I need to add a column to my table with the count of every occurrence of. So if the value is unique the column value should be 1, but if there is multiple copy i need a differente value for every row (1,2...)

The database is postgres
for example

| id | value | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 |
| 2 | a | 2 |
| 3 | b | 1 |
| 4 | b | 2 |
| 5 | b | 3 |
| 6 | c | 1 |

database example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=0e7132f3f094bd93b390ccae2e811696

Comment: In future, could you please provide your table structures as DDL (CREATE TABLE x...) and your data as DML (INSERT INTO x VALUES...) - use the fiddle service [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/).

Comment: "I need to add a column to my table with the count of every occurrence" -- no, you don't need to. Never store in the table something that can be calculated dynamically.

Comment: @mustaccio yes i have, because i need to to some other operation. it's just a temporary table. Don't assume what i need and why i need that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can done using window functions

```
select id, value, count(*) over (partition by value order by id) 
from the_table
order by id, value;
```

Comment: Wouldn't `row_number()`  be more appropriate than `count()` for the purpose (I realise the OP said "count" but I don't think that was what they meant).

Comment: @mustaccio: doesn't really make a difference here. But yes I was thinking about that as well.

Comment: Thank you so much